# How do I identify a COM calling client?

Tags: c#, com, ole

I have a COM DLL - Is there a way of identifying the application that is using it (calling a method within the DLL)? I tried

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().ToString();
```

but that does not identify the client.

Comment: Is your COM server in-process or out-of-process? What information are you trying to get about the caller? Or what are you trying to do to the caller?

Comment: That this is not possible is very much by design.  You *might* eke out some info from Process.GetCurrentProcess(), but without any guarantee that you get the client's process back.  Don't do it is the only good advice.

Comment: If I can establish the name (or other identifier about the client) from within the COM, I can adapt what it returns including NOT returning anything if it is NOT a recognised client. It is in-process.

Comment: I've got the caller with System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName; Thank you.